# need to get user input on screen in pygame

Tags: pygame

I'm finishing a project using 'pygame'.  And I haven't really done anything but re-write the snake game to include a function that will generate a multiplication question and ask the user for input. I then want to take the correct answer and give the user 10 points if the question is answered correctly. I can't figure how to do this. i get the question that flashes on the screen but no idea how to get the user's input in the same box.  Any help is appreciated...

```
def problem():
    num  = random.randint(1,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,12)
    str1 = str(num)
    str2 = str(num2)
    str3 = "What is " + str1 +" X " + str2
    text1 = medfont.render(str3, True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text1, [250,250])
```

Comment: there is no standard tool for text input in pygame, you should implement it yourself. Like adding a separate game loop which takes input and appends each key to a list for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inputbox: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/inputbox/  (You can always hack his code a bit if you want it to work differently.)